# Sort tags by number of followers (add a tab to the tag page)

Tags: feature-request, tags, user-interface

Right now, the "Tags" page supports listing the tags either in the most popular order or in alphabetical order. I think it will be interesting to see not only what tags are the most popular on questions but also what tags are the most popular **for users**, so it will be nice if we could get another tab that will sort the tags by the "most followed" order (the number of users who have that tag as an favorite tag).

I think that this order also gives a better sense of how many **experts** we have on topic X, as opposed to how many questions we have on topic X. That's something I would very much like to see.

Comment: This would be useful, I've noticed a couple of particularly well-followed tags that don't always map to the most popular tags.

Comment: Good idea. There are some tags such as 'string' used 24298 times but with 312 followers, because they are too general on their own. For comparison, 'linq' has fewer uses, but ten times the followers.

Comment: In my experience, since sometimes the most suitable tags for a question have no followers and little questions, better results are found by making a ranking of the tags that fit the topic of the question, ordering them by their amount of Watchers, and use the top 5.... later, in a bounty, seek after a few days with the following tags on the ranking, and so on, until I found any answer to my questions. So, a filter by Watchers on the Tags main page will save me a lot of time making these rankings. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34872/909869)

Answer (score 7):

Ways this feature would be used:

- Help define the scope and direction of the site, showing which tags are most relevant or interesting.
- Help with retagging. I use follower counts to determine which tags are most useful.
- Indicate where to prioritize efforts to flesh out the tag wikis.

Comment: +1; #2 and #3 seem like good reasons to me.  I'm not sure #1 would get much of a boost compared to the tab w/ number of questions for each tag.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham In my experience (on UX), the most used tags tend to represent the lowest common denominator, tending to be too broad (e.g., website-design) or too abstract (e.g., best-practices). They're generally not very good tags.

Comment: In my experience, since sometimes the most suitable tags for a question have no followers and little questions, better results are found by making a ranking of the tags that fit the topic of the question, ordering them by their amount of Watchers, and use the top 5.... later, in a bounty, seek after a few days with the following tags on the ranking, and so on, until I found any answer to my questions. So, a filter by Watchers on the Tags main page will save me a lot of time making these rankings. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34872/909869)