# Tag statistics - count and number of watchers

Tags: support, statistics, tag-watching

Where can I see a table of popular tags ordered by their **number of watchers**?

---

I ask because I believe a tag's popularity should be judged by its number of watchers rather than number of uses. Some tags (such as 'string' and 'image') are used frequently but have very few watchers. See [Sort tags by subscribers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142619/pointless-tags-small-ratio-of-followers-to-uses)

Comment: data explorer might be able to do that

Comment: see also [Sort tags by number of followers (add a tab to the tag page)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81395/sort-tags-by-number-of-followers-add-a-tab-to-the-tag-page)

Comment: @BenBrocka: I checked, that information is not currently available in the data explorer. Neither does the [API](http://api.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @BenBrocka Some related feature requests: [Let me get my favorite tags using data explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271872) and [Make tag follower count available in SEDE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308349).

Answer (score 4):

There is currently no list with tags ordered by their number of followers.

However, in the [Tags page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags), you have the tags ordered by popularity (amount of questions asked having the tag) with their count and you can see amount of watchers for each.

If you hover with the mouse over a tag name, you are able to see the number of watchers for it:

[image: Amount of watchers for specific tag]

Comment: I'd like the data in a machine readable table!!!

Comment: The tags aren't sorted by the amount of followers, rather then by the amount of times they are used, as OP stated. There is currently no page, other then SEDE, that displays tags in order of how often they are followed.

Comment: @Luuklag who said they're sorted by amount of followers? Where did you see it? (It's not in this answer that's for sure)

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar this answer implies as such, as the question asked specifically about the amount of followers. This answer no-where says that it is sorted on anything else then followers.

Comment: @Luuklag no. It clearly say "Popularity" which is the term used by SE itself, see the tab names in the tags sort options. (Popular, Name, New), so if the term "popular" is confusing by implying amount of watchers, you can start feature request asking to change it to something you find more clear. :)