# Let me get my favorite tags using data explorer

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, tag-watching

How do I get a collection of the tags I've marked as favorites?

When I hover over a tag, and click the star icon, it toggles between Favorite, Normal and Ignored. How do I find that information using the data explorer?

If not possible, I would like to add such functionality please.

Example:
On the web UI, I can go to the 'unanswered questions', then select 'my tags'. I want to filter and sort that list of questions.

Comment: For what kind of query did you want to use my favorite tags info?

Comment: @rene I am pretty sure OP want only his own favorite tags, not of other users.

Comment: @ShadowWizard well, if that is true than the FR is not as useful as it might be. With a little bit of effort you can already do what the OP wants: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/415505

Answer (score 9):

You can query Data Explorer for your favorite *questions*, but favorite *tags* are not recorded in the public data.

I'm not aware of any method beyond scraping your profile to retrieve this information, though I would imagine it will eventually be exposed via the API.

Comment: Upvoting, but not marking as an answer. I'd prefer to leave the question open until the functionality is available.

Comment: @Eris so change this into feature request. (that would just be declined, since favorite tags are not exposed anywhere publicly - i.e. I have no way to know what your favorite tags are, and doubt even moderators can tell)

Comment: Or just post a feature request that fleshes the idea (and what motivates it) out a bit more.

Comment: Regarding the API, the official apps do have that info, so doesn't it mean the API does expose it already?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I checked [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) but I can't find that. Are you sure your favorite tags on the site are exactly the same as in the app?

Comment: @rene huh, looking closer we have only searching in questions having a favorite tag, not a way to see list of all those tags. So guess you're correct.