# List of all available/popular tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'm finding it bit confusing to determine which tag to put for post. I faced this problem when I posted my first query in [WP.SE](http://workplace.stackexchange.com).

As I was new to that site, I didn't know which would be the most appropriate and most followed tag. Thanks to some of the fellow users over there, who edited and put correct tags, I was introduced to some popular tags.

Attaching the most popular tag gives maximum exposure to our post, right?

As I start typing the first letters in the tags field, matching tags pop up, which is great indeed, but this comes handy only if I know what to type.

So my question is, **is there a place where I could see all the tags used in that site (StackExchange domain) with their follower count?**

Comment: Did you see the 'Tags' link at the top of the page leading to http://workplace.stackexchange.com/tags ?

Comment: Also see [Sort tags by number of followers (add a tab to the tag page)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81395)

Comment: For any site in general, the /tags page lists exactly that. Unfortunately (but to your benefit), traffic has been slow on the Workplace, so your question will be seen on the front paage regardless of how it is tagged (and those of us who see it can help by retagging). For sites like StackOverflow, that's not the case, since it would appear on the unfiltered front page of questions for about 2.1 seconds before there were enough newer questions to push it off

Comment: With the exception of the very biggest sites (mostly just SO really), uncommon tags aren't really invisible to most users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't tag your posts with the most popular tags just because you want to get the most attention.  Your choice of tags should rest solely on the content of your post.

Take a look at the list of tags for that specific site by visiting `/tags` and there, beyond seeing what tag is the most "popular", you can read the tag wiki and possibly get more insight on the tag's meaning and use.

It goes without saying that the best way to understand what tag to use where is to simply observe.  Sit at your desk and watch how other others operate.  How *they* use the tags.

> i didnt konw which would be the most appropriate and most followed tag. Thanks to some of the fellow users over there, who edited and put correct tags

That statement brings me to my final point.  Even if you happen to choose the wrong tag, members of the community will be able to edit or suggest edits that improve your posts including your tag choice. This however isn't an excuse not to even attempt to use correct tags.

To summarize -

- Don't tag your posts with the most popular tag if it means nothing to your post.
- Trust the community to fix mistakes with tags.
- For a list of tags specific to a certain Stack Exchange site. visit `/tags`.

You could also just click the link to the `/tags` from *any* page....

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Tags also have synonyms so if you are using any appropriate keyword, often it will have a synonym that "redirects" it to a more widely-recognised tag.